# responsive image align or animation

Tags: html, css, svg

I am working on a webpage and in the header area I would like to have like this:

[image: final output]

There is a logo image, 2nd image (the one with yellow color) and some text displayed as a grid.

But I am stuck in the 2nd image. I don't know how to do it. Whether to use CSS3 animation or SVG or something else. I also want this to be responsive.

Code:

```
<header class="header">
  <!--logo image-->
        <img width="366" height="138" title="" alt="" src="logo.png">
  <!--2nd image -->
  <img id="shape" title="" alt="" src="2nd_image.png">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
.header{
    padding-left: 15px;
    min-height: 30vh;
    background-color: #00337F;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 18%;
    left: 30%;
    width: 68%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.item{
    color: white;
}
```

Codelink:  https://codepen.io/jacky6181/pen/wPNJwg

Note: I am hosting my images on Duri.me website

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I could do. I divided up the header into three sections and used SVG for the diagonal yellow line.
https://jsfiddle.net/rydnfkkL/

HTML

```
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="#" width="100%" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
  <div id="slash"></div>
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="item">Text</div>
    <div class="item">Text</div>
    <div class="item">Text</div>
    <div class="item">Text</div>
    <div class="item">Text</div>
    <div class="item">Text</div>
    <div class="item">Text</div>
    <div class="item">Text</div>
    <div class="item">Text</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  background-color: #00337F;
}
header {
  height: 30vh;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 30vh;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
header::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}
#menu {
  border-top: 5px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
}
#slash {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 10 10'> <path d='M0 10 L10 0' stroke='yellow' /></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5%;
}
.item {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #00337F;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: THIS Is great. Thanks so much! 
I wasn't sure what to use SVG or css3 animation. Using transform and rotate property I can move a line.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
html {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}
.header {
    background-color: #00337F;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 110px;
}

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
.item{ width:70%; }
.grid{
    padding-top: 38px;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;

    background: url("data:image/png;base64,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") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.menu{ text-align: center; }
.menu img{ width: 100%;
height: auto; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For tablets: */

    .col-m-3 {width: 15%;}

    .col-m-6 {width: 85%;}

    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}

    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */

    .col-3 {width: 15%;}

    .col-6 {width: 85%;}

    .col-9 {width: 75%;}

    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    /* For desktop: */

    .col-3 {width: 15%;}

    .col-6 {width: 85%;}

    .col-9 {width: 75%;}

    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 col-m-3 menu">
              <img title="" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-m-9 col-3 col-m-12">
          <div class="grid">   
           <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
            <div class="item">Text</div>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this one for once. little bit responsive